# Oracle Apex stop a dynamic Action with SweetAlert js Code

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, sweetalert

I created a DA using a SweetAlert js code but when i click in the cancel button the other actions in this DA dont stop.

This is the code that im using:

``

```
const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
  },
  buttonsStyling: false
})

swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
  reverseButtons: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  } else if (
    /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
  ) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Cancelled',
      'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
      'error'
    )
  }
})
```

``

What do i need to do to stop the actions when i push the cancel button?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `apex.da.cancel`.

Find out more on this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/apex.da.html).

Comment: Hi!
I already tried that...still dont work.
Do you any more suggestions?